# create a Google spreadsheet in a particular folder

Tags: google-apps-script

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532114/google-apps-script-addtofolder-adds-to-folder-and-mydrive) teaches how to adjust the folders of a file to move it into a particular folder, and out of the root.

It also suggests using folder.createFile to create it directly in the desired folder... but it appears createFile only applies to Docs... is there a way to create a spreadsheet directly in a particular folder?

Answer (score 9):

Since DocsList is deprecated, currently the following solution works:

```
var folder=DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName).next();//gets first folder with the given foldername
var file=SpreadsheetApp.create(fileName);
var copyFile=DriveApp.getFileById(file.getId());
folder.addFile(copyFile);
DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(copyFile);
```

Comment: I get `"TypeError: Cannot find function addFile in object FolderIterator. "` because getFoldersByName returns a FolderIterator not a folder

Answer (score 3):

Create spreadsheets using Apps Script does not work with regular Google accounts and Google Apps Standard Edition accounts. However, you can always make a copy of a dummy spreadsheet and then modify it accordingly using Google Apps Script. Here is a sample code.

```
function createSpreadsheetInfolder() {
  var dummySS = DocsList.getFileById('ID of dummy SS');
  var myCopy = dummySS.makeCopy('My new file');
  //Get your target folder
  var folder = DocsList.getFolder('ID or path of folder');
  myCopy.addToFolder(folder);
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Seems to work for Apps Standard Edition.  If it is documented otherwise, where? So we can report a problem in the docs or the functionality...

Comment: At present, creating a spreadsheet works fine for me in a regular Google account.

Answer (score 3):

The answers already given don't seem to work, maybe they're outdated.

Here's my answer (worked for me).

```
var folders=DriveApp.getFoldersByName("existingFolder");
while (folders.hasNext()) {
  var folder = folders.next();
  var file=SpreadsheetApp.create("the file that must be in a folder");
  var copyFile=DriveApp.getFileById(file.getId());
  folder.addFile(copyFile);
  DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(copyFile);
}
```

Comment: This was the solution that worked for me. The most up voted answer was giving me an error because `var folder=DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);` was returning a FolderIterator object and not an actual folder. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly, my answer is derived from the previous ones, none of which did exactly what I needed. This function has been tested with current Google Apps Script and spreadsheet documents. With duplicate folder names it will work, but move the file to the first folder returned by the API.

```html
// Arguments are a file object and a folder name.
function moveFileToFolder(file, folderName)
{
    var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);
    var copyFile = DriveApp.getFileById(file.getId());

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
       var folder = folders.next();
       folder.addFile(copyFile);
       DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(copyFile);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Now it is possible to create Google spreadsheet in a specific folder.
For that you need to use advanced drive service v2. Enable it from Advanced Services menu in google app script editor.

```
var oFile = placeGoogleSpreadsheetInSpecificFolder("my file", "target folder id");
var oSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(oFile.getId()));

function placeGoogleSpreadsheetInSpecificFolder(sSpreadsheetName, sTargetFolderId) {
    var oGeneratedFile = Drive.Files.insert({
        "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
        "parents": [{
            id: sTargetFolderId
        }],
        "title": sSpreadsheetName
    });
    return oGeneratedFile;
}
```

This solution worked perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me, I think there is no way to avoid the "remove from root" step, at least not that I know.

```
function createSpreadsheet() {
var folder = DocsList.getFolder('GAS');// this value as test for me
var root = DocsList.getRootFolder()
var newFileId = SpreadsheetApp.create('testNewSS').getId();// this defines the name of the new SS
var newFile = DocsList.getFileById(newFileId); // begin the 'move to folder process'
newFile.addToFolder(folder);
newFile.removeFromFolder(root);// had to do it in 2 separate steps 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have code like that, derived from the other question's answer... Seems like Docs are a little more equal than Spreadsheets, or I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

This question has beeen answerd in.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19610700
It is a nice solustion.

```
folder.createFile("name", '',MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
```

using anything but a empty string leaves me with a error.

Comment: Looks like a nice API, but is that API one I can run from my computer, where I have the data I want to load into the spreadsheet, or is it only runnable as a script from the Google web site, as a Google APP ?

Answer (score 0):

Just a 'heads up' for people who are reading this old answers like me. The most solutions are already deprecated. You have to use "moveTo" and you will not need to remove from root-directions or something else.

Have a look at [this link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#movetodestination) for more details.

My solution to do so:

```
/**
 * function createSS
 * @description: Creates a new SpreadSheet with imported values and directly in provided folder
 * @param {string} ssName name of SpreadSheet
 * @param {object} sheetData values as range
 * @param {object} ssFolder reference to a folder
 */
function createSS(ssName, sheetData, ssFolder = false){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(ssName);
  ss.setSpreadsheetLocale("de");
  if(ssFolder){
    // Move to provided folder
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId());
    file.moveTo(ssFolder);
  }
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();  
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheetData.length, sheetData[0].length).setValues(sheetData);    
  return sheet;
}
```

Example with folder assignment:

```
var folders = DriveApp.getFileById(ssFileId).getParents();
var folder = folders.next();
// add new file (directly in correct folder)
var sourceSheet = createSS(newFileName, relevantValues, folder);
```

( This is only working this way, if you're sure your file is in 1 folder only. Otherwise, do it with .hasNext() and a loop )