# Remove My Drive label

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

After creating a new spreadsheet and using `addToFolder()` the My Drive label remains.  Can we remove it?  Couldn't retrieve a folder id for the My Drive root to use with `removeFromFolder()`.

If not, I know we start from within a certain folder and use:

```
var folder = DocsList.getFolderById(id);
folder.createFile();
```

...but how do you do convert the file created to a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the 'my Drive' folder is the "root folder", try like this:

```
function removeFromRoot(){
folder=DocsList.getFolderById(id);
var file=DocsList.getFileById('fileID'); // or createFile...
file.addToFolder(folder);
file.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());
}
```

As for your other question about spreadsheets, have a look [at this post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641760/create-a-google-spreadsheet-in-a-particular-folder/13643101#13643101)

Comment: Was trying to loop through `getAllFolders()` by mistake. That other answer link doesn't have an example of creating a sheet with `DocsListApp.createFile()` or `folder.createFile()`. Both those methods create a PDF.  I'm missing how the file type gets specified or how / if a spreadsheet can be created that way as opposed to using `SpreadsheetApp.create()`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Serge insas was right but DocsList is now not used in Drive.

Here is my updated version:

```
function removeFromRoot() {
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadSheet.getId());

  // Remove from the root folder (files can be in multiple folders in Drive - folders are more like labels)
  // Note that "root" depends on who is logged in when running this! It is "their" drive which is the "root" folder (label)
  DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(file);
}
```