# How to Create a Spreadsheet in a particular folder via App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

Can anybody help me out,

I want to create a Spreadsheet through App Script in a particular folder. How to do that.

Presently I am doing as follow:

```
var folder = DocsList.getFolder("MyFolder");
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("MySheet");
var file = DocsList.getFileById(sheet.getId());
file.addToFolder(folder);
file.removeFromFolder(file.getParents()[0]);
```

It is not working.......

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you can no longer create **Google Docs** (Docs or SpreadSheets) using **DriveApp**, nor use **addToFolder** because **DocList** is deprecated. There is only one way to create or "move" Google Docs or Google SpreadSheets..

```
  //"Move" file to folder-------------------------------//
  var fileID = '12123123213321'
  var folderID = '21321312312'
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).getName()
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID)
  var newFile = file.makeCopy(file, folder)

  //Remove file from root folder--------------------------------//
  DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).setTrashed(true)
```

As you can see this **DOES NOT** move the file, it makes a copy with the same name in the folder you want and then moves the original file to the trash. I'm pretty sure there is no other way to do this.

Comment: When I'm using Drive as a user and I create New > Google Sheets (in a shared folder, for example), the file is created in the folder directly (if I allow it). I don't see odd copies of those files in the trash. Seems like there's a better way (but maybe the API for mortals doesn't allow it).

Comment: Alternative method without makeCopy or setTrashed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19607559/how-to-create-a-spreadsheet-in-a-particular-folder-via-app-script/64137750#64137750

Answer (score 51):

As suggested by @Joshua, it's possible to create a Spreadsheet (in a specific folder) with the Advanced Drive Service (you'll need to activate this if you haven't already, by going into `Services +`, find `Drive API` and click Add).

```
var name = 'your-spreadsheet-name'
var folderId = 'your-folder-id'
var resource = {
  title: name,
  mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,
  parents: [{ id: folderId }]
}
var fileJson = Drive.Files.insert(resource)
var fileId = fileJson.id
```

No need to move files around with this method !

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. Thank you! It should now be the accepted answer.

Comment: One thing i had to do in order to make it work: Activate "Drive API". Go to in the script editor to: Resources > Advanced Google services ... > Drive API > On

Comment: Official documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive ; Also insert() has two parameters: Drive.Files.insert(resource, fileData)

Comment: This works. (As of this comment date.)  But why Google don't fix this until now.  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createFile(String,String,String) still don't work.

Answer (score 16):

```
  folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDER_ID")
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create("SPREADSHEET_NAME")
  DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).moveTo(folder);
```

You may use the above code to achieve the same without using advanced drive services

Comment: addFile have been deprecated in July 27, 2020, here you can find how to use new method moveTo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19607559/how-to-create-a-spreadsheet-in-a-particular-folder-via-app-script/64137750#64137750

Answer (score 11):

The other answer is a bit short (and not very explicit).
While your approach is logic and should work if you replace

```
file.removeFromFolder(file.getParents()[0]);
```

with

`file.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());`

there is a better way to do the same job using the new [Drive app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFoldersByName%28String%29) and the [Folder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/folder) Class, Folder has a [method to create a file](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createFile%28String,String,String%29) and you can specify the file type using the [mimeType enum](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type).

Code goes like this :

```
function myFunction() {
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('YOUR FOLDER NAME'); // replace by the right folder name, assuming there is only one folder with this name
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
   var folder = folders.next();
  }
  folder.createFile('new Spreadsheet', '', MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS); // this creates the spreadsheet directly in the chosen folder
}
```

Comment: this seems to be a new restriction... it used to work when I published the code. It still works for other mimetypes that are NOT google docs (html, csv...)

Comment: This thread shows that the new way to do this is to use Advanced Drive Service.
https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4080

Comment: As of the current times, folder.createFile seems to the right way to creat a file in the desired folder.

Answer (score 7):

In July 27, 2020 there have been these updates:

The **File** class now has the following methods:

- file.getTargetId(): Gets a shortcut's file ID.
- file.getTargetMimeType(): Returns the mime type of the item a shortcut points to.
- **file.moveTo(destination): Moves a file to a specified destination folder.**

The Folder class now has the following methods:

- folder.createShortcut(targetId): Creates a shortcut to the provided Drive item ID, and returns it.
- folder.moveTo(destination): Moves an item to the provided destination folder.

**The following Folder class methods have been deprecated**:

- *addFile(File)*
- *addFolder(Folder)*
- *removeFile(File)*
- *removeFolder(Folder)*

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/#july_27_2020

So you can create a Spreadsheet file in a folder using `file.moveTo(destination)` method:

```
function createSpreadSheetInFolder(ss_new_name, folder_dest_id) {
    var ss_new = SpreadsheetApp.create(ss_new_name);
    var ss_new_id = ss_new.getId();
    var newfile = DriveApp.getFileById(ss_new_id);
    newfile.moveTo(DriveApp.getFolderById(folder_dest_id))
    return ss_new_id;
}

var file_name = 'SPREADSHEET NAME';
var folder_id = 'DESTINATION FOLDER ID';
var new_ssId = createSpreadSheetInFolder(file_name, folder_id)
```

Comment: move to deprecated

Answer (score 5):

You can create a spreadSheet and then add it to the folder.

```
function createSpreadSheetInFolder(name,folder){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(name);
    var id = ss.getId();
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
    folder.addFile(file);
    return ss;
}
folderId='your_folder_id'
name='my_new_ss'
folder=DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId)
createSpreadSheetInFolder(name,folder)
```

By using the folder.addFile method there's no need to use a temp file (no need to duplicate and remove file). Pretty straightforward !

Comment: addFile have been deprecated in July 27, 2020, here you can find how to use new method moveTo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19607559/how-to-create-a-spreadsheet-in-a-particular-folder-via-app-script/64137750#64137750

Answer (score 2):

I finally got the answer to my question. The following works

```
var file = DocsList.getFileById(sheet.getId());
var folder = DocsList.getFolder("MyFolder");
file.addToFolder(folder);

// remove document from the root folder
folder = DocsList.getRootFolder();
file.removeFromFolder(folder);
```

Comment: ok, I'm 7 minutes too late ;-) but have a look nevertheless... there is a better way to do it. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What is not working? Use getRootFolder in the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new spreadsheet in a file can be done using [this link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createfilename-content-mimetype) as a reference.

createFile(name, content, mimeType)

Therefore using the [enum MimeType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type) we can do:

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("your-folder-id");
folder.createFile("My File Name","",MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS)
```