# Add Spreadsheet file in a folder

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Anyone know how create a Spreadsheet file in a specific folder on Google Drive?

I have already tried the answer from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19607559/how-to-create-a-spreadsheet-in-a-particular-folder-via-app-script/19610700#19610700).

EDIT - Tried this answer :-D :

```
     //"Move" file to folder-------------------------------//
  var fileID = '12123123213321'
  var folderID = '21321312312'
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).getName()
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID)
  var newFile = file.makeCopy(file, folder)

  //Remove file from root folder--------------------------------//
  DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).setTrashed(true)
```

But the "correct answer" gives me the follow error ***"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot find function makeCopy in object Spreadsheet."***

I saw other answers but none of them work. I have already tried enable "Drive API" from "Advanced Google Services", but it's kind of complicate to work with.

UPDATE!
Just to explain, my problem is that I was creating the Spreadsheet

```
var sheetId = SpreadsheetApp.create("filename").getId();
```

And then trying to makeCopy, or addFile in a folder. Something like that:

```
<someFolder>.addFile(sheet);
```

What I detect is that to work I have to get a File type, not a string like after. So I change to the code;

```
var sheetId = SpreadsheetApp.create("filename").getId();
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(sheet);
<someFolder>.addFile(file);
```

Comment: Try using the debugger, and run each line of code one line at a time, and view the values.  [Google Documentation - Troubleshooting - Debugger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making a copy, why don't you just move it?

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID),
    folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID),
    parents = file.getParents();

folder.addFile(file);

while( parents.hasNext() )
   parents.next().removeFile(file);
```

Comment: but this doesnt answer the question. edit your question.