# Spreadsheet creation - Permissions, file location and remove file

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an Adwords script that creates a new spreadsheet by using the command below:

```
var ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.create("Name document");
```

Is it possible to create this file in a specific folder of my Google Drive?

If so; the file will have the default access (view, edit, comment) permissions as the folder has, right?

If not; is it possible to give the created file a permission as in "Everyone in [company] can edit this file"?

Furthermore, is it possible to set some sort of expiration date for the file?
I'm planning on running the script daily and old files will no longer be relevant.
I can build some sort of check to find the old file, delete it and then run the script again, but if there is some sort of expiration function that would save me quite some code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is apparently [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19607559/how-to-create-a-spreadsheet-in-a-particular-folder-via-app-script) to create Spreadsheets within folders.

You'll have to use something like this:

```
function createNewSpreadsheetinFolder(){
  var ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.create("Name document");
  var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B1TY_1aqz3fpWktMa25LbVkzQTQ");
  var ssnewFile = DriveApp.getFileById(ssNew.getId());
  var ssFinal = ssnewFile.makeCopy("Name document", targetFolder);
  ssnewFile.setTrashed(true);

  try {ssFinal.addViewers(targetFolder.getViewers())} catch(e){};
  try {ssFinal.addEditors(targetFolder.getEditors())} catch(e){};
}
```