# Google script Create new sheet file and move it to a specific folder Then copy the contents and 2 tabs from the active sheet to the newly created file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

Welcome: I will not go into the code at the beginning, but I would like to ask a few questions. To learn the logic of operation.

Question 1:

When I create a new file using the function

```
var newFile = SpreadsheetApp.create("Name new sheets")
var newFileId = newFile.getId()
```

A new file is always saved to the root directory of the google disk?

Question 2

If I always write root directory of the google disk.The only way to move a newly created file is to use

```
var TARGE_FOLDER_ID = "asdFHd4hasdasn6nJMGLSQt8das331"
DriveApp.getFileById(newFileId).makeCopy("Name new sheets",TARGE_FOLDER_ID);
```

And after copying the removal from the main google drive folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I create a new file using the function

Yes `SpreadsheetApp.create("Name new sheets")` puts files in the root directory you will have to move them

> If I always write root directory of the google disk.The only way to move a newly created file is to use

Yes something like this [Move file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36073916/1841839)

```
var folder=DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName).next();//gets first folder with the given foldername
var file=SpreadsheetApp.create(fileName);
var copyFile=DriveApp.getFileById(file.getId());
folder.addFile(copyFile);
DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(copyFile);
```

Comment: Thank you. As soon as I have found a moment, I will check the solution you have provided.